# Match any string regex

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to match any string of charicters using regular expressions in Java but have encounted a problem. I am trying to replace where a string contains `%key%` with the corrasponding value from a hashmap.

My currant regex pattern is `%([.]+)%` which seems to not work but I'm not sure why. I have tried `%([a-z A-Z 0-9])%` which seems to work fine but I would like to allow all charichters but new line and "." does not seem to allow anything but fullstops(e.g. `%...%` will worb but `%test%` won't.

I'm honestly not sure what I have done wrong, I assume I am using the fullstop in the wrong place but can't seem to find how to use it correctly.

Sorry for the horrible explaination, I can't think of how to put it better.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `%(.+)%`?

Comment: It works but for example if the input string is "The user %var1% has %var2% dollars in his account!" it would print "%var1% has %var2%" instead of "%var1%" "%var2%"

Comment: Then you can use `%([.]+?)%`. The `?` means the pattern is not greedy.

Comment: That allows nothing but dots.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the typo. I meant `%(.+?)%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use something like:

```
%([^.]+?)%
```

The `?` means non-greedy.
The `[^.]` means not full stop.

Given the input:

```
%inside1%something%inside2%
```

It will match 
  `%inside1%` and `%inside2%`

The problem with `[.]` is that it is literally a full stop.

**Edit**
If you are matching line by line, then mine will be fine. If you are matching across multiple lines then you should use [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361754/746754) answer which will explicitly exclude linebreaks from the match, so multiline queries that match % across lines will be excluded from the results.

Comment: That works perfectly, I seem to recall a full stop being any character but a new line, is this right?

Comment: @user2248702 - correct - http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html. However, if you put the full stop in '[.]' then it matches an actual full stop rather than any character except new line.

Answer (score 4):

> `I would like to allow all charichters but new line and "."`

You can use this negation based regex:

```
%([^.%\\n\\r]*)%
```

`[^.%\\n\\r]` means match anything but DOT OR `%` OR new line characters

Answer (score 1):

Use `(?<=%)(.+?)(?=%)` .

**EXPLANATION**

[image: EXPLANATION]

**Sample code:**

```
HashMap<String , String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "one");
map.put("2", "two");
map.put("3", "three");
String line="%123%";

Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(?<=%)(.+?)(?=%)");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(line);
if(matcher.find()){
      String match=matcher.group();
      Iterator<String> it=map.keySet().iterator();
       while(it.hasNext()){
           String key=it.next();
           if(match.contains(key)){
                line=line.replace(key, map.get(key).toString());
           }

        }
            System.out.println(line);
 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
%onetwothree%
```

Comment: It works but for example if the input string is "The user %var1% has %var2% dollars in his account!" it would print "%var1% has %var2%" instead of "%var1%" "%var2%"

Comment: @user2248702 Add a question mark after the asterisk to make the group non-greedy, i.e. match the shortest occurrence instead of the longest: `%(.+?)%`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.out.println("%sdfsdf%".matches("^%.+%$"));
```

I think in some situations Regex only is not enough - you should do some logic also.
You can try with `StringBuilder`.